# Вставка если нет дубликатов

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть два столбца, это id(AUTO_INCREMENT) и text(TEXT). Как при добавлении строчки(INSERT) проверять уникальность text, и если найден дубликат то ничего не делать ?

Comment: Сделать уникальный ключ на поле text и использовать insert ignore или insert ... on duplicate key

Comment: @Mike на текст вроде нельзя сделать уникальный ключ, выдаёт ошибку

Comment: тогда добавьте еще один филд с хешем текста и сделайте его уникальным

Comment: *на текст вроде нельзя сделать уникальный ключ, выдаёт ошибку* Да. Необходимо указать количество начальных символов для индексации. Это не даёт стопроцентной гарантии, если заданная длина индексирования меньше длины поля, но вероятность коллизии при достаточной длине префикса невелика... А поле с хэшем вообще никогда не даёт стопроцентной гарантии, если поле (в битах) длиннее хэша.